What is the unit cell and the bravais lattice of a perovskite?
First year PhD. student here. I keep trying to wrap my head around what kind of bravais lattice and how does the unit cell of a perovskite look? I am specifically interested in bismuth ferrite (BiFeO3) thin films, but finding an answer for any kind of general perovskite structure would be very helpful.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perovskite_(structure)#:~:text=A%20perovskite%20is%20any%20material,titanium%20oxide%20(CaTiO3).
